# Dividing input box's value from previous result in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

There are 3 input boxes for number. When I put the number in the 1st and 2nd boxes respectively, it gets calculated and returns a `result`. What I want is to divide that `result` by the third input, `value3`.

Simplifying:

input boxes X, Y, Z

Q is X and Y's calculation result

I want Q / Z (by clicking one button)

This is my code so far:

```
    const cal = () => {
                const A = parseInt(value1.value.replace(/,/g, '')),
                    B = parseInt(value2.value.replace(/,/g, ''));
                // console.log(parseInt(A), parseInt(B));
                const res = A * 0.9 * parseFloat(100 / B);

                result.innerText = `you have ${new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', 
    currency: 'EUR' }).format(res)} dollar.`;
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula could be simplified a bit and there is no necessity of converting the division result to float again, so here is my version of it:

```js
// "quick and dirty" method for defining a global variable for each input field ...
[...document.querySelectorAll("input")].forEach (e=>window[e.name]=e);

const calc=ev=>{
  if (ev && ev.target.tagName!=="INPUT") return;
  const A = parseInt(value1.value.replace(/,/g, '')),
        B = parseInt(value2.value.replace(/,/g, ''));
  q.value =  A * 90. / B;
  result.value = `you have ${new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', 
currency: 'EUR' }).format(q.value / value3.value)} dollar.`
};

document.addEventListener("input",calc);
calc(); // initial calculation
```

```html
<input type="text" name="value1" placeholder="value1" value="100"> intermediate result:<br>
<input type="text" name="value2" placeholder="value2" value="90">
<input type="text" name="q" readonly>
<br>
<input type="text" name="value3" placeholder="value3" value="1"><br>
final result = int(value1) * 90 / int(value2) / value3<br>
<input type="text" name="result" readonly>
```

Comment: thanks. but i have seperated button. if i click the button1, it calculate 1st and 2nd box and print result at the page. and when i click another button shown, it divide value3 from the result. how can i make this possible?

Comment: Why do you want to slow down the process by having to click a button? I have added the intermediate result field behind `value2`. Maybe this approach is faster and more transparent.